# Access Host Variable inside a inline echo command in Linux Script

Tags: linux, shell

All,
I am running a shell script on a EC2 instance. And am trying to define a service with the IP of the instance.

```
    MY_IP=$(curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4)

    echo '{"service": {"name": "demo", "tags": ["demo"], "port":80, "check":{"script":"curl $MY_IP:80 >/dev/null 2>&1","interval":"10s"}}}' | sudo tee /etc/demo.json
```

When I browse my demo.json file on the instance, MY_IP variable is not getting replaced.

Could you please help.

Comment: FYI, the better way to substitute a value into JSON is to use a command like `jq`. The current code works for an IP address, but it'll fail for an arbitrary string -- if that string contains literal quotes, backslashes, etc.

Comment: Thanks Charles. Have made a note of this as well. I am sure I will come across this scenario soon as my code evolves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your argument to `echo` is quoted using single quotes.  These will prevent evaluation of shell variables like your `$MY_IP`, so it will be inside there verbatim (as `$MY_IP`).

You have to close the single quotes, insert `"$MY_IP"`, then open the single quotes again:

```
echo '{"service": {"name": "demo", "tags": ["demo"], "port":80, "check":{"script":"curl '"$MY_IP"':80 >/dev/null 2>&1","interval":"10s"}}}' | sudo tee /etc/demo.json
```

Comment: Thank you so much. And thank you again for a very prompt response.